# Bash: String contains hyphen

Tags: string, bash, contains

I am trying to see if string1 contains another string2. I do this in this manner:

```
a=$(tempfile)
echo "eafg" > $a

if [[ $a == *e* ]]
then
   echo "contains"
fi
```

Now I try to see if a string contains a hyphen:

```
a=$(tempfile)    
echo "22:00:00-02:00" > $a

if [ $a == *-* ]
then
   echo "contains"
fi
```

It doesn't work. I also tried:

```
if [ $a == *--* ]
if [ $a == *---* ]
if [[ $a == *-* ]]
if [[ $a == *--* ]]
if [[ $a == *---* ]]
```

With no success...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `$a` appears to be a filename, not the file contents. So your code is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following piece of code brings problems

```
a=$(tempfile)    
echo "22:00:00-02:00" > $a
```

Here you are writing to a **file** `$a` and then try to do **string** comparison.

---

Try following

```
a="22:00:00-02:00"

if [[ $a == *-* ]]
then
   echo "contains"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You redirected the string to a **file**, so **read it from the file** while comparing.

The variable `a` contains the *name of the file* and not the contents.

Say:

```
if [ $(<$a) == *-* ];
then
   echo "contains"
fi
```

The following

```
if [[ $a == *e* ]];
then
   echo "contains"
fi
```

worked for you because the variable holding the name of the file contained the letter `e`.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the solution to what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @user1064285 Hmm.. not sure if this gave you the solution given that you've accepted an alternate answer :)  Good luck.